# How to decompile a DLL file created by MATLAB into a mat file

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

I know that we cannot decompile from a DLL (made by MATLAB) to a .mat file. But now, I have a DLL created by MATLAB (uploaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/okhmig5ta1k3oxi/LSE.dll)). Please try to convert it to mat file. Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you mean to .m file?  This would be an awful lot of work even when you know exactly how to do it....

Comment: @aschepler: Yes. I need the .m file. Could you help me

Comment: Sorry, I don't have spare time to decipher an unknown amount of assembly code, understand what it's doing, and then write some Matlab code that would do something equivalent.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer:**  Impossible.<sup>1</sup>

**Long answer:** The .m source files are encrypted by the Compiler when the dll is generated. All M-file source code is stored in a [Component Technology File (CTF)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/application-deployment-products-and-the-deployment-tool.html#bsfj66v-1), which is encrypted (and decrypted) using the AES encryption specification, where [symmetric  keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) are protected by 1024-bit RSA keys. A unique encryption key is used by the MATLAB Compiler Runtime (MCR) to decrypt the expanded contents of the CTF so it can execute the code.

A few specifics from [a MathWorks developer](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/70708#180471):

- We use the AES encryption standard to protect the M-files in CTF archive.
- When extracted from the CTF archive onto the disk, the M-files remain
  encrypted.
- Keys are encrypted as well.
- The extractCTF utility does not decrypt the M-files, but merely extracts
  them from the CTF archive.

---

<sup>1</sup>Hopefully.

Comment: We don't have any tool to do it,Right?Thanks

Comment: @user3336190 Sorry. The intention is that you should not be able to do it, unless you wrote the code. If a tool existed, MATLAB would quickly patch their deployment scheme and the tool would become useless rather quickly.

Comment: @chappjc This is cool info, thanks. Also, why should I never use length() (ever)?

Comment: @MattG Just because it picks the longest dimension, and that is error prone. It's far saver to use `size` to specify the desired dimension explicitly.